# fatal: Could not read from remote repository error while git push

Tags: github

> riya@RFL113:~$ git remote add origin_personal
>   git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git riya@RFL113:~$ git push -u
>   origin_personal masterERROR: Permission to RiyaKapuria/testing.git
>   denied to railsfactory-riya. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I'm  getting this error in GitHub

Comment: Could you specify the url of the repo and provide with the output of `git remote show origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that your are logged in or not

```
git config user.name
```

If you are logged in, try to add repository first

```
git remote add origin *your_repository_URL*
```

Comment: Please also check that you have rights to push on the particular branch